# Get notified when data changed in database

Tags: android, database

I'd like to know how can I be notified when data change in my database.
Is there a solution to this or not?
The fact is I know how to push and get data in it but I don't know how to be notified when a modification happens

Comment: It could be done using broadcast reciever!

Comment: I use a mysql database which is linked by php scripts so I don't know if I can use broadcast reciever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the responsibility changing the data in your database is your app, you should create a database layer and then create some callback to notify your app your data has an Insert, update or delete operation.

If you use sqlite like local database:

First approach, using the android SDK content provider, the content observer class. Create a content observer that monitors some table in your local sqlite.

http://www.grokkingandroid.com/use-contentobserver-to-listen-to-changes/

If you use a ORM, there are callbacks in the ORM to notify changes. For example GreenDao using AsyncSession:

```
AsyncSession asyncSession = App.getInstance().daoSession.startAsyncSession();
asyncSession.setListener( new AsyncOperationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAsyncOperationCompleted(AsyncOperation operation) {
        // do whats needed
    }
});

asyncSession.insert(MyObject);
```

If you use Realm.IO, there is a callback from the realm transaction to notify is an update is done.

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            MyObject myobject = new MyObject();
            myobject.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            myobject.setName("My object name test");
            realm.copyToRealm(myobject);
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            //realm already update
            Log.e("lh", "this callback i can use to notify. after save " + realm.allObjects(MyObject.class).size());
            realm.close();
        }
    });
```

Changues in the backend.

If the changes are in the backend. A possible solution is send a push notification and start to do a background service in the app.

In this URL you have a PHP script to do a push notification to google cloud.

https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017

You must attach the google cloud push notification receiver in you android app and create  a specific service that will do an HTTP request to download the new data  if you expose your database with a REST endpoint.

Comment: this is an external application which will update the data so I don't know if I use your idea ?

Comment: you say that the data is in your backend and is mysql, so the server should be notifiy the app that there is changues in the app in the backend side. I attach a solution.

Answer (score 0):

the most simple way is to keep a row in database and update its value when data is changed.